# Azure DevOps - YAML release pipeline variable reference not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I'm trying to reference several C# API config elements as variables in a YAML release pipeline, but it doesn't seem to be actually finding it despite other config files from the project working just fine. I'm assuming it's due to different structures of the config files, example here:

Config that won't reference:

```
<xConfig>
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="yName" Value="" />
    <Setting Name="yType" Value="" />
    <Setting Name="yProc" Value="" />
    <Setting Name="yConnectionString" Value="" />
  </Settings>
</xConfig>
```

Config that does connect variable references:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="zMsg" value="" />
  <add key="zKey" value=""/>
  <add key="zRepo" value=""/>
  <add key="zFolder" value=""/>
  <add key="zUrl" value=""/>
  <add key="zUrl2" value=""/>
</appSettings>
```

Here's the snippet from the YAML where I'm attempting to reference these elements as variables:

```
- name: yName
      value: 'yNameValue'
- name: yProc
      value: db.sp_storedProcName
```

I can't find any documentation on how to format the variable reference in the structure of "xConfig". Is there a specific variable reference naming schema I need to use here for these "Settings" child nodes? Ex:

```
- name: xConfig.Settings.yProc
      value: db.sp_storedProcName
```

Comment: I don't understand. Just having a configuration file in your repository won't magically make the variable accessible within the context of your pipeline run. Are you doing anything to actually read the file in and parse the variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the variable value in `xml configuration`, The normal setting of variables that is done for app settings won't work.

Try to set the `variable` by using Powershell script with Set-Content like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $configPath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\web.config"
      
      # Read the content of the file
      $configContent = Get-Content $configPath -Raw
      
      # Modify the content as needed (remove specific lines)
      $updatedContent = $configContent -replace '<Setting Name="yName" Value="".*', '<Setting Name="yName" Value="test" />'
      
      # Write the updated content back to the file
      Set-Content -Path $configPath -Value $updatedContent

# Publish the modified web.config as an artifact
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
    targetPath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"  # Directory containing the modified web.config
    artifactname: 'ModifiedConfig'  # Name of the artifact to be published
```

**Output:-**

***My variable set as Pipeline variable below:-***

[image]

**Value set successfully:-**

[image]

[image]